# Execute .bat file via CMD, asp.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to execute a .bat file via CMD on the IIS server where I publish these files. I put the batch files in the App_Data directory on the solution and set it to "Copy always" that I have it on the IIS from deploy.

I also have a website (.cshtml), and if i call this website, it should proceed the cmd with the batch file. I done this with this code:

```
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_data/Auto_Deploy_" + branch + ".bat");
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + filePath);
        procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\";
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
        {
            procStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        }

        procStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
```

And I start the action with:

```
Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
```

I also generated a app.manifest and edited the line

```
<requestedExecutionLevel>
```

to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

because I think, that it should be done with Administrator rights.

If I connect to the website from localhost (on the server), I direct to the webpage and this script should run, and post the output and errors on the screen.

I get always the same error:

> Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
>
> *(The system could not find path.)*

Can you tell me where the problem is?

Comment: This sounds like a horrible hack, are you sure that running batch files is the only way to do what you need to achieve?

Comment: @DavidG:
Thank you for your fast response.
The thing is, that we have a GIT-repository, and want to perform a self created autodeploy.
We commit something to our GIT-repo at another server.
The Git-Repo sends a simple webhook with GET-Parameter to this ASP.NET Site i've created.
This site should now run the batch file, which delets our old repo local on the server, downloads the new one, builts and deploys it to IIS.

Comment: So you want your website to deploy your website? Sounds a bit like Inception to me! :)

Comment: @DavidG, Sorry i've edited my answer now.

We are performing an autodeploy for our other website with this batchfile.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at a deployment tool to do this for you. I've used [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) before which lets me deploy my website right from the command line using a `git push`. Alternatively, commercial products like [Octopus Deploy](https://octopusdeploy.com/) are amazing.

Comment: If there is no other way, to perform it like I wanted to do, then surely we have to switch to tools like Kudu (Thanks for this information), but I hope, that there is a way to run it like this.

Comment: is the server.mappath returning the correct path for the cmd.bat file? from your code i think you should let the batch file to execute the command cmd.exe, and just let the application to call the branch.bat file, hope this will help you

Comment: @Hadi Hassan
Thx for your replay, yes i debugged it a few times and the path to the file is correct.
Please help me, did I understand you: I should run the bat file without opening cmd.exe?

Comment: inside the batch file, you will put all commands needed to execute run your application for example passing parameters and so on, and no need to run the cmd.exe in order to run the batch file, because once you start the process "branch.bat" it will be executed in the cmd.exe, hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you @HadiHassan.
But, currently the .bat-File won't be exectued. I don't know why, but i dont get any Erorr or Output message and the Files which will be created during the .bat execution, won't be exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you help, I did now wrote a little windows service, who is doing this work.